# Can we use cookie in wordpress and find out pages viewed, time spent on pages and no. of times user has visited the site?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

Can we use cookie in wordpress and find out pages viewed, time spent on pages and no. of times user has visited the site? If so could you guys help me out? I have a site i want to tract the page views, time spent and number of times user visits the site using Cookie.

Comment: Yes it can be done but you have to write it. You show us some code and we help. We dont write code for you.

Comment: Well, that the problem, you see, i really don't know where to start ... I have never worked with any kinds of cookies before. I hope you pretty much understand my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This WP [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stats-counter/) covers pretty much, what you're looking for I think.

- Unique User Analytics: analyze your unique users
- Statistics by city
- Statistics by country
- Statistics screen resolution
- Landing pages
- Unique visitors
- Returned Visitors (Web Page "Views")
- Stats widget (tracker analytics widget)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to code it yourself. There are multiple Open-Source projects that are good, Piwik is only one of them:
http://piwik.org/what-is-piwik/

Comment: I'll be sure to try it out. Thanks !! )